# Multiselection in prompt using contains operator

Tags: multi-select, cognos

We have a column in cognos which has the comma delimited values like (AIX1, AIX2,AIX3) in each rows. We want to multiselect the results where say AIX2,AIX3 contained. How do I do it in cognos.

Answer (score 0):

On your prompt page create a drop-down prompt.  Click it to edit the properties on the left side, and make it Multiselect->True.  Then, inside your report query, filter on [DataItem] in ?PromptName?.